# Optimal Transport and Domain Adapation

Tags: statistics, optimal-transport

I'm reading Optimal Transport for Domain Adaptation as seen here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00504

We assume that we have source domain $\Omega_S$ with variables $X^s$ and labels $Y^s$, and target domain $\Omega_T$ with variables $X^t$ and labels $Y^t$. We assume there is some transformation $T \colon \Omega_S \to \Omega_T$ and that $P_s(y| x^s) = P_t(y|T(x^s))$.

We can estimate distribution of $X^S$ and $X^T$ empirically, and then calculate the optimal coupling $\gamma_0$.

What I don't get is part 3.3 in the paper.

[image]

what does it mean to "interpolate" the two distributions here? That is, why are we even finding $\hat{\mu}$ at all? Also, for $t = 1$, wouldn't $\hat{\mu}$ just be $\mu_t$?

[image]

How is $\hat{x_i^s}$ derived here?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the notation here is erroneous. For an interpolation between $\mu_{s}$ and $\mu_{t}$ should not be parametrised by $t\in[0,1]$. I think it would make more sense if in (10) you replace the weights by, say $\tau$ instead of $t$. In that case, the interpolation at $\tau=1$ gives the expression in (12). Regarding why we may wanna interpolate at all. Classic application is in image processing. Think of two different pictures A and B and you want to transform A to B. Then the interpolation will provide a 'movie' of the transformation.

Comment: @Tobsn one thing I don't get is, when $\tau = 1$, we want to minize $W_2(\mu_t, \mu)^2$, then isn't the minimizer clearly $\mu$?

Comment: it should be $\mu_{t}$ if one is minimizing over all probabilty measures, yes. But probably here the class which one is minimising over is restricted?

Comment: @Tobsn hmm interesting, the paper didn't really mention any restriction so I'm not too sure. Also do you know how this Barycentric mapping is derived?